# Interacting with the DOM after you've added to it with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, interaction

I'm building an app that allows users to add ingredients to an array.  At the same time the items are added to the UI for the user to see.  In the append to the DOM, I add an attribute called "data-item-index".  When a user then clicks on that line item, I want the JS to be able to read the value of "data-item-index" so I can splice the array of that item.  Right now, the  click on the li can't be detected.  Probably because it was not part of the original DOM.  How do we do this sort of thing.   Interacting with DOM elements that were added by JS later.

FYI, in the code I'm just using the number "3" for testing as the index.

```
        ingredient_list = [];
        yummly_search = "";

        $(".ingredient").click(function() {
            // alert("You clicked on" +  $(this).attr('data-item-name') );
            var new_ingredient = $(this).attr('data-item-name');

            ingredient_list.push(new_ingredient);
            console.log(ingredient_list);
            // Add to the Yummly api call string 
            yummly_search = yummly_search.concat(new_ingredient + "+");
            console.log(yummly_search);
            // Show new ingredient in UI
            $("#ingredients-list").append("<li class='shopping_list' data-item-index='3'>" + new_ingredient + "</li>");
        });

        // Remove from ingredient list
        $(".shopping_list").click(function() {
            var x = $(this).attr('data-item-index');
            console.log(x);
            ingredient_list.splice(x,1);
            console.log(ingredient_list);
        })
```

Comment: Either use event delegation, or bind the handler to each new element as well. Use a named function for the latter so that you can reference it again.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: As a quick intro to Event Delegation, especially since you're using jQuery, check out [this "lesson" on the jQuery site](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added elements will need to use jQuery 'on' instead of 'click'.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click', '.ingredient', function(){

});
```

Comment: This is still a directly bound event on all elements which matched the selector `'.ingredient'` when it was run, since in this form `.on()` is a drop-in replacement for `.bind()`. If you want [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), you have to structure the call differently.

Comment: I changed it to this, and it works now.  Thanks.    

$("#ingredients-list").on("click", "li", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

Not sure if the event.preventDefault() was needed.

Comment: @JonPaulBerti That's not what was advised in this answer, though, so accepting it is somewhat misleading to future readers. `.on` is the generic function for *all* event binding, not just delegated events. `.click` is just a shorthand for what's shown in this answer.